# How to use a client websocket to connect to a remote websocket windows server

Tags: asp.net, websocket, websocket4net

Help needed please

What's is the best WebSocket client library for a .net 4.5 on windows web application hosted on windows 2008 servers to connect to a remote server web socket.

The scenario is: our web application will use a web socket to connect to a server WebSocket on a third party infrastructure. Our client WebSocket will connect and send some commands and read the responses where we can identify the information needed. So there is no interaction from the user or browser its just in the code. e.g. user clicks a button and we go and get some data, and give a message dependant on the response.

so for example our client will connect to the third party socket and pass the users car registration number and send a tell me the car details and the server socket will return the data like: make, model, year etc... so we can then display that to the user.

- **Has anyone used this library with some good success?** http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket4Net

I'm hoping someone here can provide the best approach for doing this with some tried and tested solutions. I have been thinking about a web API that handles all the socket stuff in our client so i can call it and let it handle the close connection etc.

Comment: What exactly are you really asking?  Are you asking for a library for C# that does the webSocket protocol that runs on Windows?  Or are you somehow asking for architectural advice?

Comment: sorry for not explaining properly. im asking whats the best way to create a client socket in order to access the server socket. im looking at  http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket4Net. But i want to know if anyone would recommend it. and also asking what would be the best approach to do so from a .net web application. eg create an api or just call in web forms code behind. thanks

Comment: This question seems pretty broad and non-specific.  It is hard to get good answers here without focusing your question to something more specific.  You might get lucky and someone who has done something similar might come along and share their experience, but it might be too non-specific to attract much help.

Comment: have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Nope.  I'm not the right guy for questions about a C# client application.  I was just trying to clarify what you're asking so all could understand.  It seems odd to me that the type of 3rd party API you are describing is webSocket at all.  That seems like it should be an http request/response like an Ajax call.

Comment: regarding the third pary server socket, i completely agree its seems very strange but its a very large company so they do what they like :-).
i will try and edit the question. thanks for your help